# Align buttons horizontally with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML structure for a floating panel:

```js
const heatmapHideablePanel = document.getElementById("heatmap-hideable-panel")!;
const landmarkHideablePanel = document.getElementById("landmark-hideable-panel")!;
const footscanHideablePanel = document.getElementById("footscan-hideable-panel")!;
const insoleHideablePanel = document.getElementById("insole-hideable-panel")!;

document.getElementById("heatmap-main-button")?.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
  if (heatmapHideablePanel.style.display === "none") {
    heatmapHideablePanel.style.display = "";
    landmarkHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    footscanHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    insoleHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    heatmapHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
document.getElementById("landmark-main-button")?.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
  if (landmarkHideablePanel.style.display === "none") {
    heatmapHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    landmarkHideablePanel.style.display = "";
    footscanHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    insoleHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    landmarkHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
document.getElementById("footscan-main-button")?.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
  if (footscanHideablePanel.style.display === "none") {
    heatmapHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    landmarkHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    footscanHideablePanel.style.display = "";
    insoleHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    footscanHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
document.getElementById("insole-main-button")?.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
  if (insoleHideablePanel.style.display === "none") {
    heatmapHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    landmarkHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    footscanHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
    insoleHideablePanel.style.display = "";
  } else {
    insoleHideablePanel.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#floating-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80%;
  left: 97%;
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
}

.subpanel {
  position: relative;
}

.hideable-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  right: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.icon-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.icon-container:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <div id="heatmap-panel" class="subpanel">
    <div id="heatmap-hideable-panel" class="hideable-panel" style="display: none;">
      <button id="heatmap-move-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/drag.png"></button>
      <button id="heatmap-rotate-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/rotation.png"></button>
      <button id="heatmap-transparency-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/visibility.png"></button>
    </div>
    <button id="heatmap-main-button" class="icon-container main-button"><img src="assets/heatmap.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="landmark-panel" class="subpanel">
    <div id="landmark-hideable-panel" class="hideable-panel" style="display: none;">
      <button id="landmark-move-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/drag.png"></button>
      <button id="landmark-transparency-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/visibility.png"></button>
    </div>
    <button id="landmark-main-button" class="icon-container main-button"><img src="assets/destination.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="footscan-panel" class="subpanel">
    <div id="footscan-hideable-panel" class="hideable-panel" style="display: none;">
      <button id="footscan-transparency-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/visibility.png"></button>
      <button id="footscan-move-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/drag.png"></button>
      <button id="footscan-rotate-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/rotation.png"></button>
    </div>
    <button id="footscan-main-button" class="icon-container main-button"><img src="assets/foot.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="insole-panel" class="subpanel">
    <div id="insole-hideable-panel" class="hideable-panel" style="display: none;">
      <button id="insole-transparency-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/visibility.png"></button>
      <button id="insole-move-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/drag.png"></button>
      <button id="insole-rotate-button" class="icon-container"><img src="assets/rotation.png"></button>
    </div>
    <button id="insole-main-button" class="icon-container main-button"><img src="assets/insoles.png"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make 4 main buttons aligned vertically. When I click one of them, I want to display a hideable panel with 2-3 more buttons aligned horizontally.
The problem is that when I click one of the main buttons, the corresponding hideable panel displayed with its elements aligned vertically. I attached a picture showing what happens when I click on the upmost right button (the orangeish one)
How can I align those hideable panel buttons horizontally?

[image]

Comment: Try adding top: -10px to your hideable-panel, it does the trick

Comment: @Dave111 I tried, but it just moved the hideable panel 10px up. The buttons in it (the left column of buttons in the picture) are still aligned vertically.

Comment: a working example with show hide script will helpfull for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you add the Javascript you use? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Gerard Yes, I added the Javascript code to the post. It's just a simple button handling mechanism

Comment: When you remove the ! character at the end of lines 1-4 of your Javascript, I believe it works as expected.

Comment: yes as per @Gerard comment it is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/jfat5skm/

Comment: @Gerard Thank you, it's working! If you have time for it, can you explain why is it working? And also, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?